# How to troubleshoot this WearOS crashes?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I've noticed lately a lot of crashes coming from Samsung Galaxy Watches 4, which are relatively new to WearOS platform. All of that happens outside of my app and I have no clue how to troubleshoot it. Any pointers are appreciated. I don't have a real watch for testing, only an emulator that doesn't show any of that.

```
Type
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 000000000009c360  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  #00  pc 000000000006d9c5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (epoll_wait+16)
  #00  pc 0000000000011b45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+128)
  #00  pc 0000000000011a6b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+62)
  #00  pc 00000000000bb649  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+26)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:206)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7690)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:593)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:995)
```